# magento show hide option in list.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9

I added below code my list.phtml on change it will show the div. First product it's working fine. if i change 2st product 1st product value only change

```
<Select id="colorselector-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>">
                           <option value="red">Red</option>
                           <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
                           <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                        </Select>
                        <div id="red" class="colors" style="display:none"> red... </div>
                        <div id="yellow" class="colors" style="display:none"> yellow.. </div>
                        <div id="blue" class="colors" style="display:none"> blue.. </div>

                            <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function() {
        $('#colorselector-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>').change(function(){
            $('.colors').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you are using same `ids` for your colors.

```
<div id="red" class="colors" style="display:none"> red... </div>
<div id="yellow" class="colors" style="display:none"> yellow.. </div>
<div id="blue" class="colors" style="display:none"> blue.. </div>
```

Using `$('#' + $(this).val()).show();` code jQuery will get first element matching with id.

Try updating your colors' ids.

```
<div id="red-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>" class="colors" style="display:none"> red... </div>
<div id="yellow-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>" class="colors" style="display:none"> yellow.. </div>
<div id="blue-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>" class="colors" style="display:none"> blue.. </div>
```

And update your jQuery code
`$('#' + $(this).val() + '-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>').show();`

Comment: Can you please check this i have a same problem over here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175956/magento-datepicker-not-showing